# Traffic jams driving on the D1 from Praha to Brno

Tags: driving, routes, czech-republic, traffic

We will leave tomorrow morning to Brno. Are there are any road works that might cause jams? I saw that just before Brno there is a long part of workings, it's possible to Block the cars flow. 
Any alternative routes?

Comment: If you have roaming data use Waze. It saved me 30 minutes on saturday when there was a jam in a road works before Brno. It navigated me to empty road in beautiful country that went parallely to the highway.